# SQL Server : how can I ignore the last 5 characters of a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and using SQL Server 2012 and I am trying to ignore the last 5 characters of a string... I have this simple query

```
Select MarketIdentifier from Markets
```

I have tried this

```
select SUBSTR(TRIM(MarketIdentifier), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(MarketIdentifier))-2) AS "MarketID" 
from Markets
```

but I get the error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
>   'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

The `MarketIdentifier` has around 20 characters and I just want the first 15 characters. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: FWIW, `TRIM()` can be accomplished on older versions with `LTRIM(RTRIM())` but you seem to have taken a bunch of syntax from some other database platform (`SUBSTR` and `LENGTH` do not exist in SQL Server). `"MarketID"` is a bad idea too IMHO - use `[MarketID]` or just `MarketID`.

Comment: My guess is Oracle syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first 15, you would use the `left()` function:

```
select left(MarketIdentifier, 15) 
from Markets;
```

Your question is slightly more complicated, though.  To remove the last five characters, you can do:

```
select left(MarketIdentifier, len(left(MarketIdentifier, 15) ) - 5) 
from Markets;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(MarketIdentifier, LEN(MarketIdentifier) - 5) AS MyTrimmedColumn  AS "MarketID" from Markets
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code just SELECT your query and use the `trim()` function for however many characters you want. This should work.